# JPA annotation Map with hibernate, and best relational model

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I'm trying to annotate this :

```
public class                        Keyword {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Integer                 id;
    //Missing annotation
    private Map<Keyword, Integer>   keywordRelated;
}
```

I found this [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyJoinColumn.html) but they don't deliver the relational model, and it's not the exactly same model. And I can't figure out how their tables are.

Comment: Why would a related keyword be in a map and not just a list, e.g.     List<Keyword> related ?

Comment: Because I need to store a ratio with it which I store in an Integer. Anyway I want to know how to do it even if it isn't the best design.

Comment: Look at @mappedBy. If you need to store a ratio, you need an Association Class.

Comment: Thank you be still I want to know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following tells only how to map Map which does have entity as a key (depending about case can be that there is better solutions, like intermediate object with ratio).

[@ElementCollection](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html) is designed for mapping such a collection. @OneToMany cannot be used when value is not entity.

By default following mapping

```
@ElementCollection
private Map<Keyword, Integer> keywordRelated;
```

Maps to following table in database (assuming that name of table for Keyword entity is Keyword and not affected via @Table-annotation):

```
Keyword_KEYWORDRELATED (
  Keyword_ID (PK, FK to Keyword ID), 
  KEYWORDRELATED , 
  keywordRelated_KEY (FK to Keyword ID)
)
```

If default naming for database tables and columns is not sufficient, those can be customized as follows:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name= "keyword_to_related_keyword")
@Column(name="ratio")
@MapKeyColumn(name="related_keyword_id")
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name="some_other_preferred_name")
public Map<Keyword, Integer> keywordRelated;
```

Comment: Could you please give me a quick sketch of the database table those annotation will make.